# Send array of 2 integers as argument

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, arguments

I am trying to make this C++ code more abstract, easier to see and understand, and less space occupier. It is a function that takes a string and two integers for a size and a position.

```
HWND CreateButon(string Title, const int[2] Size, const int[2] Position) {
    // Create the control, assign title, size and position
    // Return HWND
}

HWND MyButton = CreateButton("Button1", [100, 20], [10, 10]);
```

I know the last one is wrong. I just wrote it that way so you can see what I mean. I would like to send the size and position values directly as an argument. I could use `structs` but they must be declared before. The same with some other kind of variables. I just want to send them in the arguments as groups of two integers and I wonder if there's a workaround for it. More than anything else it's just for the sake of having it compact and simple.

Comment: If C++11 is an option, tuples and uniform brace-initialization are one solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass a pair instead of an array:

```
HWND CreateButton(string Title, std::pair<int,int> Size, std::pair<int,int> Position);

CreateButton("Button1", {100, 20}, {10,10});                            // C++11
CreateButton("Button1", std::make_pair(100,20), std::make_pair(10,10)); // C++03
```

Alternatively, in C++11 only, you could pass `std::array<int,2>`. That needs slightly stranger aggregate initialisation `{{100, 20}}`, but means you won't lose ability to index it using `[]`.

Personally, I'd probably prefer to define the structs you describe; that would give more type safety and self-documentation, which I tend to value more than compactness. In fact, I might even go as far as giving them an `explicit` constructor (rather than allowing list initialistion) so you have to use "named arguments":

```
CreateButton("Button1", Size(100,20), Position(10,10));
```

Comment: That's better than my solution

Comment: And, since the structs are defined elsewhere, compactness is retained. If C++11 can be used, this is a perfect solution.